# Working around lack of partial member specialization with specific design constraints for performance

Tags: c++, performance, templates

As part of writing performance-sensitive numerical simulation code, a design issue came up that I've spent a few days thinking about and cannot find a satisfactory solution. As part of my simulation, I have a rather large container class template, partial specializations of which contain the data members relevant to that part of the simulation. The transformations applied to that data, however, can vary wildly and are supplied via a number of different template arguments. Here's a simplified minimal toy example of the kind of behavior I have in mind:

```
enum AlgType1 {Alg1Kind1, Alg1Kind2};
enum AlgType2 {Alg2Kind1, Alg2Kind2};
enum AlgType3 {Alg3Kind1, Alg3Kind2};

template<int D=2, AlgType1 T1=Alg1Kind2, AlgType2 T2=Alg2Kind1, AlgType3 T3=Alg3Kind1>
struct Grid {};

template<AlgType1 T1, AlgType2 T2, AlgType3 T3> // etc.
struct Grid<2, T1, T2, T3> {
    const int N1, N2;
    const SomeData d1, d2;
    Grid(const GridParams params) : N1(params.N1), N2(params.N2), d1(params.d1), d2(d2) {}

    template<AlgType T1>
    SomeData AlgImplementation;
};

template<AlgType1 T1, AlgType2 T2, AlgType3 T3>
template<>
SomeData Grid<2,T1,T2,T3>::AlgImplementation<Alg1Kind1>() {
    return d1*N1 + d2*N2; // just do something with the data in Grid
}
```

Unfortunately, this approach can't work because even full explicit member template specializations are not allowed unless the class template is also fully specialized. In my case that would mean explicitly spelling out every possible combination of all the different algorithm types I've written, so that isn't an option. The problem would be trivial if I could use conventional runtime polymorphism with virtual functions, however the performance overhead is something I cannot afford (yes, I've benchmarked it, and it matters). The simple template alternatives I've tried so far either don't scale (in terms of code bloat) as more algorithms and more kinds of algorithms are added (as in the case of conventional CRTP) or come with significant issues of their own.

The least bad solution I've found so far involves a simple policy-based design implementation for the algorithms, with static member functions for the actual work. However, this decouples the algorithm implementations from the main scope of the Grid class, so I have to either pass in the data by each variable or, alternatively, pass in a pointer to the relevant Grid instance using something like:

```
template<class Grid, AlgType1 T1> class Alg1Policy {};
template<class Grid> class Alg1Policy<Alg1Kind1> {
    static SomeData run(Grid grid) {
        return grid->d1*grid->N1 + grid->d2*grid->N2;
    }
}
// and then in the partially specialized Grid class, the last two lines change to:
SomeData AlgImplementation() {
    return Alg1Policy<decltype(this),T1>::run(this);
}
```

Either way I incur a considerable syntax overhead that cannot be entirely mitigated as well as some additional pointer chasing in the latter case. I am therefore dissatisfied with this solution. I've also considered some other options, involving `enable_if` and similar constructs, but the complexity of those approaches grows far too quickly as the number of algorithms increases. Do note that, despite the trivialized examples here, I also have algorithm specializations that depend on two or more different template parameters having a specific combination of values at once.

The basic issue here is that I'd like to retain my data in the same scope as the behaviors I generically assemble from components (either policies, traits or other constructs) to cut down on the boilerplate and avoid unnecessary performance costs. In the absence of language support for partial member specialization, is there a better way I haven't thought of? Or am I, perhaps, thinking about this entirely the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

You could employ [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) to 'specialize' your member functions.

```
#include <type_traits>

enum AlgType1 {Alg1Kind1, Alg1Kind2};
enum AlgType2 {Alg2Kind1, Alg2Kind2};
enum AlgType3 {Alg3Kind1, Alg3Kind2};

template<int D=2, AlgType1 T1=Alg1Kind2, AlgType2 T2=Alg2Kind1, AlgType3 T3=Alg3Kind1>
struct Grid {};

template<AlgType1 T1, AlgType2 T2, AlgType3 T3> // etc.
struct Grid<2, T1, T2, T3> {
    const int N1, N2;
    const SomeData D1, D2;
    Grid(const GridParams params) : N1(params.N1), N2(params.N2), D1(params.d1), D2(params.d2) {}

    template<AlgType1 Ta>
    std::enable_if_t<Ta==Alg1Kind1,SomeData> AlgImplementation()
    { return D1*N1 + D2*N2; }

    template<AlgType1 Ta>
    std::enable_if_t<Ta==Alg1Kind2,SomeData> AlgImplementation()
    { return D1*N1 - D2*N2; }
};
```

Note that you can apply SFINAE differently, for example on the type of an argument

```
    template<AlgType1 Ta>
    SomeData AlgImplementation(std::enable_if_t<Ta==Alg1Kind2>* =nullptr);
```

or of a second template parameter

```
    template<AlgType1 Ta, typename E=std::enable_if_t<Ta==Alg1Kind2>>
    SomeData AlgImplementation();
```

etc.

Btw, what kind of algorithm are you implementing? (I'm just curious).

Comment: I've had bad experiences with having to chain `std::enable_if` (before the `_t` version existed) and producing fragile unmaintainable code in the past, but this actually seems to work great at first glance. I'll write up a prototype for one of the more complex implementations I have at the moment and, unless I run into major issues or someone suggests an even better solution, accept this answer tomorrow, thanks! To answer your question, this is the Lattice Boltzmann part of a larger fluid-structure interaction solver for physics research.

Comment: `std::enable_if_t<C,T>` is just an alias to `std::enable_if_t<C,T>::type`. I don't quite understand how this gave you *fragile unmaintainable code* and also what you meant by *chaining* `std::enable_if`.

Comment: My issues with maintainability were in a different context, doing template metaprogramming in a different project. My one leftover issue with this solution is that I have to refer to every member function using the full list of template parameters - `AlgImplementation<T1>`, etc. Due to the way aliases and alias templates work, I can't do away with the boilerplate with a simple `using` statement, even though all the information is available at compile time and in the same scope. Is there an easy way around that?

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem (and cannot see how your original attempt avoided it). Please create an example code of where this problem occurs. Usually, you never *refer* to a member function, but simply call it. There is no such thing as a *using statement*; in a *using declaration* you can simply say `using base::AlgImplementation;`.